# passing php variable through ajax

Tags: jquery

In jquery ajax function,  how can php variable pass through url?

php : `send.php?id=<?php '.$news_id.' ?>`

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ABOVE URL",
 data: str});
```

Comment: You can't. php is a serverside language. Javascript client side. Best thing would be to store the id in a hidden input or something in html so you can retrieve it with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: cant jquery post to links like send.php?id=111  ??

Comment: Of course it can. If you write your JS file to include that text there, or dynamically generate the URL in client-side JS use some other variable written to JS or HTML by PHP.

Comment: Brad Christie posted the right answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send.php?id=<?php echo $news_id; ?>',
    data: str
  });
  ...
```

Like that?

Comment: Both insightful and humorous. :)

Comment: If you can't have a little fun it's not worth the expense. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to pass the value of the href to the URL of the ajax call? Assuming you're clicking on a link?

```
$('a.thisLink').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: $(this).attr('href'),
     data: str
    });

});
```

---

If you want to pass a value from a form to send.php, you can do that like this.

```
function sendFormData(formData){

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'send.php',
     data: formData
    })    

};

// when the form is submitted
$('form[name=foo]').submit(function(){

    // pass the entire form?
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    // or just one input?
    var formData = $('form[name=foo] input[name=bar]').val();

    sendFormData(formData);

});
```

Comment: I want to insert value of a form in database

Comment: Check out the update, is that what you are looking for? You might want to elaborate a bit more on your question.

Comment: sendData(formData);  --> sendFormData(formData);
when calling the function. Just to be correct. :)
(But I think that's not the right answer, I think Brad Christie is on the good way. :) )

Comment: Whoops, you are correct sir. I was just stabbing in the dark. My ESP aint so great. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use PHP to create valid HTML and/or JS files on your server.
2. Wait for them to be sent to the browser over the Internet.
3. When they arrive, the browser will execute whatever is there.

Comment: Yes, I know the The issue theorically :))